# Error using subfloat and centerline in figure

Tags: subfloats

I would like to have 6 figures side by side and I have 4 series of these figures. I have the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{romannum}
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centerline{
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{img/Amp/340_GT.png}}\\}
    \centerline{
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\\}
    \centerline{
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{img/Amp/601_GT.png}}\\}
    \centerline{
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{img/Fourth/289_PR.png}}\hspace{0.6mm}%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\\}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig: Sos Prediction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figures are shown correctly but I get errors at last subfloat of each line:

`undefined control sequence`

and

```
{\includegraphics [width=1cm]{example-image.png}}...
l.323 ...hics[width = 1cm]{example-image.png}}\\}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I can not figure out why this error appears, any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And please replace all your figures (which we do not have) by `example-image`. Furthermore, TeX breaks the line at the undefined control sequence, so preserving linebreaks when quoting error messages is crucial.

Comment: `\subfloat` is provided by the package `subfig` but you don't load this package.

Comment: @Famaz please have a look at the answer below

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks for your response but the main problem was what P.M. mentioned. I didn't add subfig package!

Comment: Don't use \\ in `\centerline{...}` as it adds a second line.  Use `\centering` (no argument) instead.  BTW, the subcaption package also has a version of `\subfloat`..

Answer (score 1):

This may point you in correct direction

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=bf}
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{420}
\caption*{420}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{421}
\caption*{421}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{422}
\caption*{422}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{423}
\caption*{423}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{424}
\caption*{424}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{425}
\caption*{425}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=bf}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{420}
        \caption*{420}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{421}
        \caption*{421}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{422}
        \caption*{422}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{423}
        \caption*{423}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{424}
        \caption*{424}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{425}
        \caption*{425}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=bf}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{420}
        \caption*{420}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{421}
        \caption*{421}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{422}
        \caption*{422}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{423}
        \caption*{423}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{424}
        \caption*{424}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{425}
        \caption*{425}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=bf}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{420}
        \caption*{420}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{421}
        \caption*{421}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{422}
        \caption*{422}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{423}
        \caption*{423}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{424}
        \caption*{424}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{425}
        \caption*{425}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After half of year ...
Since your main problem is solved by  @P.M. comment, here are some off-topic suggestion how you can correct/improve your MWE:

- because all images has the same width, you can use common settings for it by `\setkeys{Gin}{...}`
- for centering of images on page is better than `\centerline{...}` to use command `\centering`
- for starting new row of images just insert empty
- instead of fix distance between image used `\hfil`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=13mm}
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}

    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}

    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}

    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfil%
    \subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image}}
\caption{caption}
    \label{fig: Sos Prediction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is very nice as an answer. Probablily it is useful for me. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much!